# What is $Z$ in collision theory of chemical reactions?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, physical-chemistry, kinetic-theory

According to collision theory given by Max Trautz and William Lewis the rate of chemical reaction is proportional to $Z$ *(number of collision per second per unit volume of reaction mixture)*

Suppose **a**,**b** and **c** react to form **d**.

Then would Z include every possible collision like:

Collision between two different molecules like **a** and **b** or **b**and **c** or **a** and **c**.

Collision between two same molecule like between **a** and **a** etc.

Collision between all three reactants at same time.

And most importantly does $Z$ include collision between reactants and products like **a** collide with **d**?

Or does $Z$ only include all collision *(effective or non effective)* of all reactants **a**,**b** and **c** at same time?

Here is what I want to say:

[image]

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic yes but collision theory is based Kinetic theory of gases so I thought physics SE is better place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, normally Z would imply collision of all the three reactants in the same time, since thee molecules have to be close to each other in order for chemical transformation to occur. Consequently, [the law of mass action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_mass_action) would involve product of the densities of all the three reagents:
$$K\sim [a][b][c].$$

However, if there is an intermediate product, then we can talk about pairwise collisions only, e.g.
$$
a + b + c = ab + c = d.$$
But in this case we are talking about two subsequent chemical reactions.

Note that the reactions with many intermediate products are quite common - e.g., the difference between combustion and conventional oxidation reaction is the former involves formation of many intermediate products, which makes it very fast. See [*Can we call rusting of iron a combustion reaction?*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/751515/247642)

Answer (score 0):

Such reactions are not usually elementary reactions, but there is typically some reaction schema, requiring particular time order of collisions.

Also, if an elementary reaction has just a single product, the reaction rate depends on collisions with other molecules to pass the reaction energy while honoring momentum conservation.

E.g. $\require{mhchem} \ce{2 H(g) <=> H2^{*}(g) ->[collision]H2(g)}$